# HTML <img> tag is not working

Tags: html, image, xhtml

I am using following simple HTML :

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
    <html>
    <body>
            <img src="loading.gif" alt="MISSING GIF"> 
            <img src="j.JPG" alt="MISSING JPG">              
    </body>
    </html>
```

`loading.gif` and `j.jpg` are present in same directory as html file. `loading.gif` is displayed fine in ie 8 but `j.jpg` doesn't load.

When I use firefix, both images display correctly.

Please help

Comment: I tried with few other .JPG files. Some are displayed and for missing JPG message is diplayed.  Could there be issue with image .jpg file. All files diplay fine in firefox or opened directly in ie.

Comment: You should provide URLs in cases like this, the URL of the page and the URL of the image.

Answer (score 7):

Check that `JPG` file extension is uppercase in the file system.  I suspect that it is lowercase.  Also be sure to close the image tag.

```
<img src="j.jpg" alt="MISSING JPG"/>
```

Comment: In file system name of file is j.JPG. I assume in widows environment case shouldn't matter. In HTML I changed to j.JPG, still doesn't work.

Comment: I tired using a different .jpg file. This code works. How to find problem with .jpg file. It opens correctly in ie but not using HTML.

Comment: @Aman Khanna Try opening it with paint and saving it with a different file name.

Comment: I did open image using paint an dvarious other image editors and changed size and othe rparameters and saved using different name. Still it doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

```
<img src="loading.gif" alt="MISSING GIF">
```

will be like this

```
<img id="ImgEmployee" src="Photos/loading.gif" alt="MISSING GIF" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, i deiscovered that when working with wordpress you should use this code for images:

```
<img src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/images/example.jpg" alt = "example">
```

Answer (score 1):

Was the img file originally in another extension? If so, revert to the original extension.

I took a screenshot on my Windows PC in .png format. I changed the extension to .jpg (thinking it would work the same as my Mac). IE didn't like it, but Firefox was fine with it.

```
<img src="1.jpg" />
```

I changed the extension back to .png, and it worked fine in both browsers.

```
<img src="1.png" />
```

Answer (score 0):

lowercase the extension, and close the img tags, you are using XHTML 1.0 Strict !

```
<img src="loading.gif" alt="MISSING GIF" />  
<img src="j.jpg" alt="MISSING JPG" />
```

**EDIT**: maybe you hit a IE8 bug... +1 to the question :)

Let's try like this: using a page really XHTML 1.0 Strict compliant,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
   <head>
      <title>hi!</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div>
         j.JPG : <img src="j.JPG" alt="MISSING JPG" /> 
                 (upper case) <br/>
         j.jPG : <img src="j.jPG" alt="MISSING JPG" /> 
                 (first lower case, others upper case <br/>
         j.jpg : <img src="j.jpg" alt="MISSING JPG" /> 
                 (lower case) <br/> 
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

create two copies of the file, so you will have the three files listed above. Then run the page in IE8 and tell us which one is working...

Comment: `<img>` is a none-container tag and hence, there is no need to close it.

Comment: Lion, try to validate it in validator.w3.org: `Line 5, Column 54: end tag for "img" omitted, but OMITTAG NO was specified"`. Sorry... but no.

Comment: I closed the tag and also tried .jpg as well as .JPG in code. Still it doesn't work. Not sure why .gif file is diplaying correctly.

Comment: Are you sure the file is not jpeg, with the "e" ? For a better help, run "dir" or "ls" and paste the result here, editing your answer

Comment: I tried .jpeg as well it doesn't work. I am using windows, so I assume it is not case senstive.

Comment: Run DIR in your directory, then paste it here please

Comment: I checked using dir command, file name is j.JPG. EVen when I use j.JPG in HTML file, it doesn't work.

Comment: I tired with all combinations j.JPG, j.jPG, J.jpg. None of them work. I tried on a different image file, it works.  I suspect it has to do with quality of image file. What could be the reason . All of the image files open fine directly on all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

Is it broken in IE9/10 too?

Also, if the code you posted above is exactly what's in your file, you have an incorrect character (`) right before the doctype declaration.

Internet Explorer breaks when your HTML is wrong, browsers like Firefox are much more lenient and try and fix things for you.

Comment: Some other .jpg images are displayed correctly. I assume it has to do with specific files, instead of HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because of the specific images. Check if you have permission to use those files.
I also had the same problem. I had two OS(Ubuntu and Windows) running and the image I was using was coming from Windows local disk. After I solved this permission issue, it worked.

Answer (score 0):

recently i was working in a web project using WAMP server. i placed my web site under **`c:/wamp/www/my_site`** folder and referenced an image from this folder on a page. the image did not display. i referenced another image at `desktop`...bingo, it worked. i think its *the permission thing*...
:)

Answer (score 0):

Did you checked if there is some difference in the header? This happens sometimes that due to some GET requests header changes to something like this: {https:www.xyz.com/?id=blah-blah}. 
Now since no such file exist in the directory, the img tag remains clueless that actually where it had to look for the resource. You need to change send header again to the same page so that no GET request get connected to the address this time.
Took me a long time to figure out.

Answer (score 0):

Check for cors setting, sometime server might be configured to reject such requests and if accessing the image from different that there are high chances of that the resulting server might be switched off the hot loading of images.

Resources:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Answer (score 0):

Another possible issue that happened to me:

**Your adblocker might be blocking the image.**
Yes, even if the image is hosted on the same website. In my case, I had a bunch of images under `/banners/imagename.jpg`, which uBlockOrigin all blocked from loading. That's why not even the alt tag showed up.

Check the `Network` tab, it should show you there what went wrong. In my case, this is what I found:
[image]